# Meteor: select2 package stopped working after node_modules cleanup and meteor reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, jquery-select2, node-modules

I have a meteor project, where I have a few jquery plugins installed and working fine - some via NPM, some via Atmosphere.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "eyeconnect",
  "description": "Teleoftalmologia",
  "version": "1.0.2",
  "dependencies": {
    "autosize": "^3.0.21",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "bcrypt": "^0.8.7",
    "bootstrap-select": "^1.12.2",
    "croppie": "^2.5.0",
    "dropzone": "^5.1.1",
    "fibers": "^2.0.0",
    "html-pdf": "^2.1.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.15.1",
    "select2": "^4.0.3",
    "spin.js": "^2.3.2",
    "typeahead.js": "^0.11.1"
  }
}
```

.meteor/packages:

```
# Meteor packages used by this project, one per line.
# Check this file (and the other files in this directory) into your repository.
#
# 'meteor add' and 'meteor remove' will edit this file for you,
# but you can also edit it by hand.

meteor-base@1.1.0             # Packages every Meteor app needs to have
mobile-experience@1.0.4       # Packages for a great mobile UX
mongo                   # The database Meteor supports right now
blaze-html-templates@1.0.4    # Compile .html files into Meteor Blaze views
session@1.1.7                 # Client-side reactive dictionary for your app
jquery@1.11.10                  # Helpful client-side library
tracker@1.1.3                 # Meteor's client-side reactive programming library

es5-shim@4.6.15                # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers.
ecmascript@0.8.1              # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax in app code

iron:router
twbs:bootstrap
accounts-ui@1.1.9
accounts-password@1.4.0
less@2.7.9
accounts-ui-unstyled@1.2.1
check@1.2.5
ejson@1.0.13
joshowens:accounts-entry
aldeed:collection2
aldeed:autoform
rajit:bootstrap3-datepicker
aldeed:autoform-bs-datepicker
msavin:mongol
edgee:slingshot
eluck:aws-sdk
email@1.2.3
force-ssl@1.0.14
standard-minifier-css@1.3.4
standard-minifier-js@2.1.1
horka:swipebox
random@1.0.10
meteorhacks:zones
matb33:collection-hooks
shell-server@0.2.4
meteorhacks:aggregate
percolate:synced-cron
dynamic-import@0.1.1
```

After several months, I decided to cleanup my local copy, by performing the following actions:
* remove the node_modules folder
* meteor reset

After this, I ran the app locally, and everything seems to work fine, except for the jquery select2 plugin. On the Blaze page where it's used, I always get the error that select2 is not a function in jQuery.

Calling code:

```
$("#cid10")
  .select2({
    allowClear: true,
    data: dataSet
  })
```

Error logged on browser:

```
Error: $(...).select2 is not a function
```

Important to say that I have no code change, just executed the cleanup actions mentioned above.
After some faildd attempts to make it work, I decided to checkout the repo (same code version) into another folder, built and run the project, and still the same error. However, on other machines running the same checkout, it works fine. Doesn't seem to be a browser cache/issue either - I cleaned cache/history, tried different browsers, still the same error.

I executed a simple jquery query via the console, and analyzed the function prototype of the returned object, and indeed the function select2 is not listed there. So it seems like for some reason, when I import select2 into the javascript file of the template where it's supposed to run, it does import, but is not registering itself within jquery as a new function.

Since select2 is installed via NPM, I'm importing it with:

`import select2 from '/node_modules/select2/dist/js/select2.full.min.js';`

Alternatively, I tried to copy both the js and css files from the node_module dist folder into my project's client folder instead of importing them, but get the same result.

Any help here would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Show your `package.json` and `.meteor/packages` files, please.

Comment: @Styx: updated with the content of the files.

Comment: I'd suggest to remove npm's `select2` and add meteor's one: https://github.com/nate-strauser/meteor-select2

Comment: Maybe that could solve the problem, but it still doesn't explain why it worked before, and just due to the reset it stops working. It's a bit scary not to understand why it simply won't work anymore via NPM... no meteor release change, no code change, simply project reset, and only this plugin stops working...

Comment: Where exactly in the code you're calling `$(...).select()`?

Comment: The code displayed above:
```$("#cid10")
  .select2({
    allowClear: true,
    data: dataSet
  })```
Just for the record, $("#cid10") does return a jquery object (I logged to be sure). I also checked the meteor wrapper package for select2, and it does nothing but include the select2.js and select2.css files into the client code. I also tried that myself, copying the files from the node_modules dist folder directly into the client folder, same result.

Comment: I still don't grasp why, but something made it work again:
* checked all recent changes in package.json (looking for removed packages)
* found that another package (dropzone) was upgraded from 4.2.0 to 5.1.1, then back to 4.3.0, then to 5.1.1
* I applied the same changes, and magically select2 restarted working

I have no idea still why, but select2 is working again...